# Subscription of a Subject, between two modules, is not working properly in angular 5

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am working on an Angular 5 project. I have to show app loading spinner often times. For that I have created a shared module and spinner component inside the module. Here is my module file,

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import {TranslateModule, TranslateLoader} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import {TranslateHttpLoader} from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import { ConfirmationDialogComponent } from './confirmation-dialog/confirmation-dialog.component';
import { SharedMaterialModule } from 'app/shared/modules/shared-material.module';
import { TimePickerComponent } from './time-picker/time-picker.component';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { SpinnerComponent } from './spinner/spinner.component';
import { SpinnerService } from './spinner/spinner.service';

// AoT requires an exported function for factories
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
    return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
                deps: [HttpClient]
            }
        }),
        SharedMaterialModule
    ],
    declarations: [        
        ConfirmationDialogComponent,
        TimePickerComponent,
        SpinnerComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        TranslateModule,
        TimePickerComponent,
        SpinnerComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        SpinnerService
    ],
    bootstrap: [ ConfirmationDialogComponent ]
})
export class UtilityModule { }
```

Here is the spinner component,

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { SpinnerService } from './spinner.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription'

@Component({
    selector: 'app-spinner',
    templateUrl: './spinner.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./spinner.component.css']
})
export class SpinnerComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    spinnerStateListener: Subscription;
    showSpinner: boolean = false;

    constructor(private spinnerService: SpinnerService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.registerSpinnerStateListener();
    }

    private registerSpinnerStateListener() {
        this.spinnerStateListener = this.spinnerService.spinnerState.subscribe((spinnerState) => {
            this.showSpinner = spinnerState.show;
            console.log(spinnerState);
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.spinnerStateListener.unsubscribe();
    }

}
```

In order to notify the spinner when should it show and hide I am using `RxJS` `Subject` in a service file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
@Injectable()

export class SpinnerService {

    spinnerState = new Subject<{ show: boolean }>();

    changeSpinnerState(state: boolean) {
        console.log(state);
        this.spinnerState.next({ show: state });
    }

}
```

And I am using this spinner all over the app. When I am emitting a new value from another component, which is inside another module, subscription is not working in spinner component. Here is the component file and the secondary module,

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SpinnerService } from './spinner.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-contact-form',
    templateUrl: './contact-form.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./contact-form.component.css']
})
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private spinnerService: SpinnerService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.spinnerService.changeSpinnerState(true);
    }  
}
```

---

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { CrmRoutingModule } from './crm-routing.module';
import { SharedMaterialModule } from '../../shared/modules/shared-material.module';


import { ContactFormComponent } from './contacts/contact-form/contact-form.component';
import { SpinnerService } from '../../shared/modules/utility/spinner/spinner.service';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [        
        ContactFormComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        CrmRoutingModule,
        SharedMaterialModule,
        UtilityModule
    ],
    providers: [
        SpinnerService
    ],
    bootstrap: [

    ]
})

export class CrmModule {

}
```

When I am emitting a value it is reaching up to the `changeSpinnerState` method in spinner service file. But subscription in spinner component is not working. What will be the error in my code? Thank you

Comment: You provide `SpinnerService` twice, that means there will be 2 instances, one for each module. You will need to have a `SharedModule` to provide the service there, and import that module to your `AppModule` so everybody will use one service.

Comment: @HarryNinh I tried your suggestion and it worked. Why don't you post it as answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With EventEmitter (not tested, maybe you need some import) you could do something like this...

Service, declare a EventEmitter to pass boolean data.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
@Injectable()

export class SpinnerService {

    spinnerState = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

}
```

Component with the spinner html.
Subscribe to event and do whatever when the event rises depending of status (true/false)

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { SpinnerService } from './spinner.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription'

@Component({
    selector: 'app-spinner',
    templateUrl: './spinner.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./spinner.component.css']
})
export class SpinnerComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {


    showSpinner: boolean = false;

    constructor(private spinnerService: SpinnerService) { 
            this.spinnerService.spinnerState.subscribe(
                (status:boolean) => showSpinner = status;
            );
    }
}
```

Whenever you have to show the spinner emit the event with the true/false

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SpinnerService } from './spinner.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-contact-form',
    templateUrl: './contact-form.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./contact-form.component.css']
})
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private spinnerService: SpinnerService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.spinnerService.spinnerState.emit(true)
    }  
}
```